# Soft-boiled Ostrich Egg Sous Vide

Tags: eggs

Tomorrow morning I want to try a soft-boiled ostrich egg in my sous-vide cooker at a temperature of 65°C.
Does somebody know how long the egg has to stay in the sous-vide cooker? I've found an online calculator which says 1h40min.
Do you think that's enough time? I'am a little bit skeptical. :D

Comment: The duplicate I suggest provides an answer that uses sous vide, however, I'm not sure it is a satisfactory response.  65C seems too high for traditional soft boiled.  See: http://cookingissues.com/primers/sous-vide/purdy-pictures-the-charts/.  Also, there are calculators to determine how long it would take for the center of a sphere (I know not exactly a sphere) of a given size to reach temp. in sous vide.  I would find one of those to zero in on time.